# Zsh tab completions for subdirectories of an arbitrary parent

Tags: zsh, cd, zsh-completion

So, to better explain what I'm asking for, I am writing a zsh plugin for quickly navigating up directories and I want to offer the ability to traverse into a directory by specifying a starting directory in $PWD.

For example, if I am in a directory `~/example/first/left/second` and I wanted to go to a directory `~/example/first/right`, I could call `$ up first/right`. I managed to get the functionality working just fine, but I want to offer tab completions in the same way `cd ..[/..]*` does.

At the moment, here is what I have

```
_up() {
  local -a args
  args=(`echo ${PWD#/} | sed 's/\// /g'`)
  _arguments ':paths:($args[@])'
}
```

And so I currently have tab completions working for all of the initial options available, but past that point I have no idea how to get zsh to tab complete like paths past this point.